# Child processes gives seg fault on exit function

Tags: c++, signals, fork, multiprocessing, freebsd

My environment:

- **FreeBSD 9.1**  and I got a pre-forked multi-process environment.
- A main process, a poller to manage workers (to decide busy or avaiable) and workers.

If I send a `SIGTERM` to main process it is all right, if count of workers is not high. If `high (x > 20)` I get seg faults.

I got two truss outputs, one of them is normal exit and the other has seg fault.

**gdb output of core file :**

```
Die: DW_TAG_unspecified_type (abbrev = 62, offset = 1535499)
    has children: FALSE
    attributes:
        DW_AT_name (DW_FORM_strp) string: "decltype(nullptr)"
Dwarf Error: Cannot find type of die [in module /usr/local/lib/gcc46/libstdc++.so.6]
Die: DW_TAG_unspecified_type (abbrev = 62, offset = 1535499)
    has children: FALSE
    attributes:
        DW_AT_name (DW_FORM_strp) string: "decltype(nullptr)"
Dwarf Error: Cannot find type of die [in module /usr/local/lib/gcc46/libstdc++.so.6]
```

**truss output of normal exited process:**

```
> close(0)                                         = 0 (0x0) close(7)   
> = 0 (0x0) gettimeofday({1360957175.665250 },0x0)           = 0 (0x0) write(5,"2013-02-15 21:39:35.665 [64591] "...,64) = 64 (0x40) close(5)
> = 0 (0x0)
> 
> sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x
> 0) = 0 (0x0)
> 
> sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,0x0,0x0)                 = 0 (0x0)
> 
> .............. .............. so many same sigprocmask call
> 
> 
> sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,SIGHUP|SIGINT|SIGQUIT|SIGKILL|SIGPIPE|SIGALRM|SIGTERM|SIGURG|SIGSTOP|SIGTSTP|SIGCONT|SIGCHLD|SIGTTIN|SIGTTOU|SIGIO|SIGXCPU|SIGXFSZ|SIGVTALRM|SIGPROF|SIGWINCH|SIGINFO|SIGUSR1|SIGUSR2,0x
> 0) = 0 (0x0)
> sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,0x0,0x0)                 = 0 (0x0)
> process exit, rval = 0
```

**process, that has seg fault :**

```
> gettimeofday({1360954514.547064 },0x0)           = 0 (0x0)
> write(5,"2013-02-15 20:55:14.547 [7580] I"...,63) = 63 (0x3f)
> close(5)                                         = 0 (0x0)
> SIGNAL 11 (SIGSEGV)
> process exit, rval = 0
```

It gives seg fault when the process tries to call sigprocmask. I didn't call sigprocmask explicitly and suspect race condition for call to sigprocmask. Did you encounter race condition, that is related with sigprocmask ?

Answer (score 0):

> It gives seg fault when the process tries to call sigprocmask

I don't see that. It seems, the crash follows the closing of the 5th file-descriptor. It further appears, the descriptor 5 gets a log-message (with a timestamp) written right before getting closed.

Your "master" daemon tries to clean-up, and dies trying. I suggest, attaching gdb to it at run time -- just before sending the SIGTERM. When the SIGTERM is sent, tell gdb to continue.

When the SIGSEGV is sent, investigate.

I'd also highly recommend running the daemon under valgrind. You are likely to catch a lot of nits that way...

Comment: hi i solved the problem it was buffer overflow. when the program tries to give back memory, i take seg fault because of BoF. thanks..

Comment: Always use valgring on on your code. Always. It is available for Linux and FreeBSD and there is simply no excuse not to make a test-run using it. It would've pointed this buffer-overflow problem to you faster, than it took you to write-up the question.
It may _still_ help you by finding other problems...